# Partialy decrypt Data

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have 16 byte des encrypted data and i want to decrypt the problem is my routin only decrypt first 8 byte and for byte 9 it throw exception Bad Data my data has no padding exactly 16 byte of data
here is my code

```
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        List<byte> resData = new List<byte>();
        try
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();


            byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray(_key);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(bytes, new byte[8]), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            cryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(cryptoStream);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                resData.Add(reader.ReadByte());
            }


        }
        catch { }
        return resData.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting the mode and padding *after* creating the decryptor? That looks like a bad idea to me. Try moving those property setter statements earlier (e.g. directly after creating the provider.)

Comment: oh very bad mistake thanx it solved my problem

Comment: @JonSkeet Post that as an answer? Then we can upvote, accept and move on.. :-)

Comment: @DuncanJones Too late :P, Codes beat him to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to set the properties on `cryptoProvider` before creating the crypter
2. No need to jump all those stream hoops, just call `TransformFinalBlock`
3. Your crypto is *extremly* weak. DES has a really small key-space and can be broken by brute-force.

An improved version of your code could look like this:

```
byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray(_key);

using(DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    cryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    using(var crypter =  cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(bytes, new byte[8]))
    {
        return crypter.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```